# Entity framework 4.1: a very special relationship

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship, fluent-interface

I have in my database a table *(AccessControl)* that describes a sort of users "access control list" for the informations contained in the table *Customers* and other tables.

**Example:** the entity CUSTOMER is marked by the EntityId #1. If a user belongs to the department #6, he can access the records of customer #16 and #31, but he can't for #14, that can viewed by user in department #3:

```
Table ACCESSCONTROL:

    EntityId    PrimaryKey  DepartmentId
    1       16      6
    1       31      6
    1       14      3
```

Here an example of the classes I am using in the domain:

```
Public Class Customer
   Public Property Id As Integer
   .......
   Public Overridable Property Acl As ICollection(Of AccessControl)
End Class

Public Class AccessControl
   Public Property EntityId As Integer
   Public Property PrimaryKey As Integer
   Public Property DepartmentId As Integer
End Class
```

How can I describe this relationship into the DbContext definition using a fluent Code First approach?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are foreign keys defined in your database? Hint: EF uses same rules as database (except it doesn't support unique keys).

Comment: Hi, in the database I defined only a foreign key relation for the DepartmentId field with the Departments table, not included as an entity in the domain and in the DbContext! AccessControl table hasn't strong relationship with other entities, because it can contains rules for records belonging to various entities, marked by the EntityId field!
Note that ALL the three fields in AccessControl represent the primary key of the table!

Comment: So the `PrimaryKey` column is shared by multiple entities (if `EntityId` has different value) to build virtual relation?

Comment: Yes, it's true. I need to set the requested relationship, so, when I will post an instance of a new customer to the controller, so I can persist the customer record (Create action), I can also correctly persist the informations contained by the "Acl" property of the customer class. Depending on the context, I might post the Acl property with a known value for EntityId and DepartmentId and, regarding the PrimaryKey property, the identity value of the new customer obtained using the requested relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly it is not possible to setup this relation in EF. There are many reasons why it will not work but the base is: unless you are able to set this relation in DB you cannot set it in EF as well. Your relation is data driven and EF has very limited support for data driven mapping - for example TPH inheritance which will not work in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you, I expected this answer!